# AG Grid: checkboxes for leaf nodes when using row groups and multiple auto columns

Tags: ag-grid

Is is possible to get a checkbox to appear for leaf nodes in row groups when the grid is configured to display multiple columns for the groups?

Plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/KlEOO7ro9WvlYHDU
in this instance I want checkboxes to appear for the "Athlete" column but *only* when the leaf nodes are visible

[image: checkboxes should appear in the highlighted area only]

If I add `'checkboxSelection': true` to the column definition then the checkbox is shown even when the group is collapsed:
[image: checkboxes are appearing on non-leaf rows/nodes]

---

The AG Grid documentation has an example of nearly I want but that only works when all of the groups appear in a single column and the group column has a field assigned to it ahead of time
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#example-groups--checkbox-selection

[image]

---

I may be able to work around it with CSS or a custom renderer but I'd rather do it with configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I can use the function form of `checkboxSelection` and inspect whether the current node is a group or not

```
checkboxSelection: (params) => !params.node.group;
```

Updated working plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/x38j1tDGuJoKIOUg

[image]

Comment: This helped me with the "opposite" need - I only wanted checkboxes on the group rows - and used this: checkboxSelection: (params) => params.node.group,